MFC Automation events are working in Excel VBA but not in VBScript
I have created an MFC automation application and also added a source interface (outgoing interface) for events. I can create the COM object and get the event notifications in Excel VBA, but not in VBScript. I checked the MFC application multiple times if something is wrong, but everything seems correct. I tried Dialog based and SDI both, but both have the same problem. I tried with an ATL project which works absolutely fine in both (VBA and VBScript).
Here is Excel VBA - this works:
Private WithEvents foo As Automate

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set foo = New Automate
    foo.Show
End Sub

Private Sub foo_OnShow()
    MsgBox "VBA Event called Succeeded"
End Sub

And here is VBScript - this does not work:
Set obj = WScript.CreateObject("Automate.Application", "ob_")
obj.Show()

Sub ob_OnShow()
    MsgBox "Automate Client: OnShow"
End Sub

The VBScript creates the object and call the method Show() when the second parameter ob_ is not passed. But when ob_ is passed, the script creates the object, queries for IDispatch successfully, and then releases the object for some reason. I tried changing the Sub to Function too. I get the following error:

Any ideas?
Thanks all!
Environment:
Win11, Visual Studio 2022

Found the problem.
The following method is overridden:
virtual BOOL GetDispatchIID(IID* pIID);

which is returning IID_IDispatch rather then IID_IAutomate.

Did you also find a solution? If not then you might want to add this information to your question instead of posting it as an answer.

Your program exits immediately after .show.
Normally you do
Do
   Wscript.sleep 1000
Loop

At the end of the main sub.
Your program is two lines. In WScript, your program exits after the second line. Your event handler exits as well.
In WScript you have to keep your program running if you want events.
This has been true for 29 years.
